# Resetting a password is not working - WTForms/Flask-SQLAlchemy/Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a problem with updating a password. I have 3 functions for a reset password function in my project.

send_rp_email - sends a link to the user who forgot their password

reset_request - user enters their email to get an email and a token is generated to identify their account

reset_token - password is reset

The function, reset_token does not work at all and I don't understand why. Everything works until the line if `form.validate_on_submit()`. I don't seem to understand why.

```
#works
def send_rp_email(user):
    token = user.get_token()
    mess = Message('Password Reset Request', sender="app@gmail.com", recipients=[user.email])
    mess.body = f'''This email has been sent since you want to reset your password.
If you did not request to reset your password, please ignore this email.
{url_for('reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}'''
    mail.send(mess)

#works
@app.route('/requestpass', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_request():
    check = check_user()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('adash'))
    form = RequestResetPass()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        send_rp_email(email)
        flash('An email has been sent to your email address.', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('requestrp.html', form=form)

#does not work
@app.route('/resetpass/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_token(token):
    check = check_user()
    form = ResetPass()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if check == 1:
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = Users.verify_token(token)
    if user is None:
        flash('Invalid token', 'warning')
        return redirect(url_for('reset_request'))
    #does not work from here:
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_pass = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user.password = hashed_pass
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('resetpass.html', form=form)
```

Here is the form that I have used:

```
class ResetPass(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Reset Password')
```

Here is the HTML file where I'm resetting the password. I don't think that there are any mistakes here but I'm adding it for context:

```
{% include "html/homeheader.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/enterdata.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <title>Reset Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="enterdata">

            <div class="enterdata-logo">
                <p>Reset Password</p>

            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(id="left")}}

                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                            {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                    {% else %}
                            {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(id="left")}}

                    {% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
                            {{ form.confirm_password(class="is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                    {% else %}
                            {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.submit(class="enterdata-button")}}
                </div>

                <br>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show: (1) the raw POST sent from the browser (2) the values in request.form (show their `repr`s ) (3) the contents of `form.errors` after validation (4) the contents of `form.form_errors` after validation.

Answer (score 0):

In your html form you need to add {{form.hidden_tag()}} to account for the CSRF code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    {{ form.password.label(id="left")}}
    {% if form.password.errors %}
        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
           {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```